# sqlite3 select from empty table = no select?

Tags: database, sqlite, select

I usq sqlite3 (on Android) and try to return a default value, if a select has to handle `NULL` values.

Normally this works:

```
SELECT ifnull(NULL, 12);
12
```

With a variable:
    SELECT ifnull(var, 21) from (select NULL as var);
    21

But the moment I use a table and this table is empty, then I don't get anything:

```
SELECT ifnull(_id, 1) FROM empty_table;
<nothing here>
```

Even returning a simple number is not possible:

```
SELECT 123;
123
SELECT 234 FROM empty_table;
<nothing here>
```

Why does that happen? How can I still get a value out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit different.

When using SELECT with rows, ifnull() is evaluated once per row, so you need at least one row.

You could probably try something:

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT _id FROM empty_table LIMIT 1), 1)
```

Comment: I really like this version and [the one with `max(...)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428174/sqlite3-select-from-empty-table-no-select/7428238#7428238). After hard thinking I will give this one the `solved` because it works in every case, where the other one only solves the cases where you can use the sqlite functions. I have such a case, though. So I will implement the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
select 1 from the_table
```

SQL returns always one row (at most) for each input row. If the table is empty, you will not get a single row.
If the table has ten thousand rows, you will get ten thousand time the number 1 (even though your program probably only select the first one, it is somewhat inefficient).

```
SELECT ifnull(_id, 1) from the_table
```

That is also rather unspecified behaviour: Without any ORDER BY, you will just get a random _id.

```
select 1
```

In the case when there is no table (not all databases support this), it is like selecting from a table with just a single row (and no columns).

> How can I still get a value out of it?

How about

```
select ifnull(max(_id), 1) from the_table
```

That will always return exactly one row, even when the table is empty, and you know which _id you are getting.

Comment: I like this one most, because it is really clear to read what the programmer wants to achieve and it works perfectly. [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428174/sqlite3-select-from-empty-table-no-select/7428216#7428216) only got the `solved` because it probably works in more cases. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A column from a table containing no rows is not equivalent to a null value

Comment: That's actually wrong and not helpful. That it isn't equivalent was already clear from the question. At least you could've explained the difference and I bet you could also found an answer to the "what to do instead?" if you know so much about it that it is that clear to you.

Comment: @erikb: No, hugh jadick is correct and is trying to be helpful. When you issue a select against a table with no rows, you get the empty set, and the empty set is not equivalent to a null value. It is not clear from your question that you understood this: `But the moment I use a table and this table is empty, then I don't get anything...`  One infers that you were baffled by the behavior.

Comment: @erikb - sorry if I offended you with my answer. As Tim has pointed out I did not believe that you already understood this point and that as a result you would think I was being condescending or similar. Also I was not aware of the "LIMIT 1" syntax, so at the time of answering I did not think it was possible. I agree I could have been more expansive with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`ifnull(_id, 1)` checks whether the value of `_id` is `null` or not in each row of the query results.

If the table is empty, there are no rows to check, so the `ifnull` never gets tested.